# javascript and html forms

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that is validated using HTML, I have couple of functions some of them can access the form and the other can`t!

here is my form:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="javascript:submitForm()" method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="a" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>email:</th>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="sikas@sikas.x10.mx" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Message:</th>
            <td><textarea type="text" id="message" name="message">msg</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and this is my script, it is divided into two parts, one of them is with the form in the same file and the other is in another file:

this is the part with the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    if(name.length == 0 || email.length == 0 || message.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Name Required\nEmail Required\nMessage Required");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        var address = email;
        if(reg.test(address) == false)
        {
            alert("Email Invalid");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var form;

function submitForm()
{
    if(check() == false)
        return false;
    else
    {
        form = document.getElementById('contactForm').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('contactForm').innerHTML = "<h3>Sending ...</h3>";
        send();
        setTimeout("restoreForm()",1000);
    }
    return false;
}

function restoreForm()
{
    document.getElementById('contactForm').innerHTML = form;
}
</script>
```

and this is in the file:

```
// JavaScript Document
function createObject()
{
    var request_type;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
        request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();
var usr;
var psw;
function send()
{
    alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
    alert(document.getElementById('email').value);
    alert(document.getElementById('message').value);

    contactName = encodeURI(document.getElementById('name').value);
    contactEmail = encodeURI(document.getElementById('email').value);
    contactMessage = encodeURI(document.getElementById('message').value);
    http.open('get', 'send.php?name='+contactName+'&email='+contactEmail+'&message='+contactMessage);
    http.onreadystatechange = loginReply;
    http.send(null);
}

function loginReply()
{
    if(http.readyState == 4)
    {
        var response = http.responseText;
        alert(response);
        if(response == 0)
            //document.getElementById('submitForm').innerHTML = "<h6>Sending Failed</h6>";
            alert('failed');
        else
            //document.getElementById('submitForm').innerHTML = "<h6>Message Sent</h6>";
            alert('sent');
        //setTimeout("restoreForm()",1000);
    }
}
```

need help in making the script from the file access the form fields.

***UPDATE:***

I have managed to solve this problem. The problem is in this function

```
function submitForm()
{
    if(check() == false)
        return false;
    else
    {
        form = document.getElementById('contactForm').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('contactForm').innerHTML = "<h3>Sending ...</h3>";
        send();
        setTimeout("restoreForm()",1000);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function `send()` connect to another page and sends data to email through it, when I have changed the `innerHTML` of the `form` before calling the function made the function to `break` when try to access a field that doesn`t exist.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Are you getting errors? Is your script running at all?

Comment: nothing! the alerts in the separate file doesn\`t run but the script in the same file with the form runs.

Comment: Maybe check to see if the other file is included in your HTML as a script tag.  In fact, you should post your head section for us.

Comment: I have added the file, but the js in the file can`t access the form

Answer (score 1):

Replace `submitForm` in:

```
document.getElementById('submitForm').innerHTML = "<h6>Message Sent</h6>";
```

And

```
document.getElementById('submitForm').innerHTML = "<h6>Sending Failed</h6>";
```

With `contactForm`

Comment: I found where the error is and solved it. Check the post I will update it.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use JQuery?  All of this code you're writing from scratch is packaged into a small, tight, reusable JavaScript library that was designed to let you focus on your business goals, not reinventing the wheel.

My suggestion is to check out http://jquery.com/ and go through some of the examples.  I believe it will save you a lot of time and headache in the future.

Remember, your employer is paying you to solve problems the further their business goals, not solve the same problems that other developers have already solved for you.

Comment: I had the same code working with me in another script. But it doesn`t work in this one.

Comment: I have solved the problem, you can check the post to see the answer.

Comment: With a smaller function, the next programmer who comes in and takes over, long after you're gone, won't make the same time-sucking mistake you did by overlooking an id attribute.  It depends on how much time you have available for refactoring of course, but I always suggest using code that will make sure that when you finally leave the organization to move on to bigger and better things that you leave it in a state where others can easily pick up where you left off.

Comment: He may not have the time, he may not be in a position to suggest a change in libraries or dependencies. He may have a lot of legacy code that would take time to refactor and test. I agree in principle with using jQuery or something like it to make life easier, but I don't like when people blanket insist that it will solve others' problems, since introducing it may not be possible without solving other problems.

Comment: Sure, I understand.  But hopefully I've encouraged the raw JavaScript hold-outs to use these well documented and well supported tools in their next project.  They have to start somewhere; otherwise, they're just going to be doing the same things over and over again and wondering why it's so hard.